# What do these Visual Studio warnings mean?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-config, web-config-transform

My Web.Config Transformations are not getting published - and I think the error has to do with these warning(s) I'm getting.

Using Visual Studio 2010, I'm playing around with my `Web.Config` / `Web.Config.Debug` files.

In my `.Debug` file, I get the following warning listed numerous times.

```
No element in the source document matches '/configuration'
```

I think it lists it for each *section* that exists in the `.Debug` file.

So with the following sample Web.Config.Debug file .. that will be listed twice. (i'm guessing, the first one is for `<connectionStrings>..</>` and the second is for `<system.webServer>...</.>` )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:SupressWarnings="false">

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Foo" connectionString="Server=foo;Database=Foo;uid=foo;password=foo" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear />
                <add name="ETag" value="Dev_IIS" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: I'm having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593671/why-wont-my-web-config-transforms-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/04/web-publishing-warning-quot-no-element-in-the-source-document-matches-configuration-hibernate-configuration-quot.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20gunnarpeipman%20%28Gunnar%20Peipman%27s%20ASP.NET%20blog%29) which suggests that the transformer is choking on xmlns= attributes.

I changed my Web.config file from this:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <connectionStrings>
    etc...
```

to this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    etc...
```

...and lo and behold, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I created a new web application project (targetting .net 4.0), changed the Web.Release.config to contain exactly what you pasted above. I then went to web.config and added the following:

```
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Foo" />  <------------------------added this
  </connectionStrings>
```

I then changed the configuration to release and published the web application. The published application contained the following in web.config

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="Foo"
     connectionString="Server=foo;Database=Foo;uid=foo;password=foo"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  <-------this got added
```

So I am not sure where the problem is in your case.

Comment: Try creating a new project like I did and see if you are able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm having this same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593671/why-wont-my-web-config-transforms-work). It would seem there's something in the Web.config that the transforms don't like. I wish I knew what...